# Tox packge error: substitution key 'posargs' not found

Tags: virtualbox, openstack, tox

I need to install horizon package of openstack cloud software on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on Virtualbox to be able to run Chipster. I have followed the protocols provided by docs.openstack website:

```
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/quickstart.html
```

And everything works fine up until the section:

> tox -e runserver

which returns the error:

```
tox.ConfigError: ConfigError: substitution key 'posargs' not found
```

The same error occurs just typing tox command.As I searched on the net, this error belong to the version 1.7.0 of Tox and was solved in later versions, The version installed by

```
sudo apt-get install tox
```

is 2.3.1-4 and the corrections which were supposed to solve this issue in version 1.7.0 provided here:

```
https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/tox/pull-requests/85/fix-command-expansion-and-parsing/diff
```

seems to be already added to the 'tests/test_config.py' and 'tox/_config.py'. I am completely out of ideas. I was wondering if anyone have had the same problem and how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I have been reporting this error since I installed tox==3.7.0. You can use

```
pip show tox
```

to view your own tox version

It would be nice to reduce the version to 3.6.0.

```
pip install tox==3.6.0
```

reboot